# Azure and ASP Authentication

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, console-application, database-migration

Im am converting an application to be used with an Azure database. I am having some issues with ASP membership though. I have found some articles on this but not really what I am doing.

The problem I am having now is I am using a Migrator.NET console application to do database Migrations. My first migration sets up the ASP membership parts using the following code.

```
// Install Membership and Roles to the database with the Asp.Net installer.
SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connection.ConnectionString);
SqlServices.Install(connectionBuilder.InitialCatalog, SqlFeatures.Membership | SqlFeatures.RoleManager, connection.ConnectionString);
```

This causes the InstallCommon.sql error.

I found this article from another post.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx

I installed the Microsoft.AspNet.Providers package but that's where I get stuck.

Now I'm getting the error "The database connection string has not been set."

I have a connection string setup in a db.config file which worked before I added the new package. Does the connection string need to be somewhere else now? Is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: In web.config, does `<membership/>`'s `connectionStringName` match with the one inside `<connectionStrings/>` ?

Comment: That's what I'm a little confused about. Since its a Console application will it use web.config? I don't have <membership> setup anywhere. I think its just part of the SqlConnectionStringBuilder. I'm not sure if the AspNet.Providers is what I need in this situation.

Comment: It seems like I need to get rid of that code all together and execute these scripts instead.

http://www.joshrharrison.com/archive/2013/01/20/asp.net-sql-membership-provider-in-sql-azure.aspx